# How can i insert a specific uuid into h2 database using sql script

Tags: sql, h2, uuid

I am using a h2 database to run my tests and i need to insert some default values in the database prior to testing. I'm trying to write an sql script for this however, i am having an issue inserting a uuid as a value into the relevant table.

I tried inserting the uuid as follows; `insert into user_profile_table (profile_id, user_id) values (1, 'c80d54d3-500d-4539-9479-8e8961477193');` however i get an JdbcSQLDataException error stating: Value too long for column.

I assumed this is because the user_id column type is BINARY(16) so i decided to try the following query `insert into user_profile_table (profile_id, userkeycloak_id) values (1, UNHEX(REPLACE('c80d54d3-500d-4539-9479-8e8961477193', '-','')));` however, then i get an error stating: JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "UNHEX" not found; SQL statement. I read online that the h2 DB does not support the unhex function. I tried to look for others means of converting the the uuid to a format compatible with the h2 database but havent had any luck finding a viable solution.

Hence, my question is: is there any query i can use to insert the uuid (in a BINARY(16)) format into the h2 db table? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why not just change the datatype to varchar?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I read that the most efficient of way storing uuid's is in binary format and that storing them in varchar format uses over double the storage space, and means bigger indices and slower lookup.

Comment: how much data are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry i dont really understand the question, could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: What is your main database system? In H2 there is a dedicated `UUID` data type that you should normally use, but if you really need to use the same data type and the same commands in two different systems possible solution will depend on them. Some database systems don't support standard binary string literals or casts, for example.

Comment: The main database system is MySql

Answer (score 3):

To insert a UUID value into `BINARY(16)` column you can use standard binary string literals in both MySQL and H2:

```sql
insert into user_profile_table (profile_id, user_id)
values (1, X'c80d54d3500d453994798e8961477193');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution by microsoft  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Please take from your link that which addresses to the question, if you just want to provide a link for the user find for themselves, we tend to put it in comments